# How to attribute an Amazon affiliate link to the Amazon Product API?

Tags: amazon-product-api

Before having access to the API, this is how I was generating my affiliate links:

`https://www.amazon.com/dp/PRODUCTASIN?tag=my-affiliate-tag`

And this has been working just fine.

But now I have access to the API and I'm gonna use it to get the prices for the products I'm displaying for my users.

https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/troubleshooting/api-rates.html

From the DOC LINK above, it made me think that the links generated from the Product API are different from the links I've been using so far.

This is what it says:

> Your account will earn a usage limit of 1 TPD for every 5 cents or 1 TPS (up to a maximum of 10 TPS) for every $4320 of shipped item revenue generated via the use of Product Advertising API 5.0 for shipments in the previous 30-day period.
> You can **verify that your sales are being attributed to your calls to PA API** by checking for the following:
>
> - You are using the links provided by Product Advertising API 5.0 when linking back to Amazon.
> - You can check to see **sales that have been attributed to Product Advertising API** 5.0 through generating a Link Type Performance report through the Associates Central reports tool.
>   """

Right now, this is the link I'm using (before having access to the API):

`https://www.amazon.com/dp/PRODUCT_ASIN?tag=my-affiliate-tag`

I create them directly on my website code. And they are working fine.

This is the link I'm getting from Amazon API:

`https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005IWH0YE?tag=my-affiliate-tag&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1`

Are those links any different? Do I need to use the link from the Amazon API in order to keep my access to the API every month? I found the documentation very confusing.

The only difference seems to be the `&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1` part. Do I need to append it to the links I've been using so I can let Amazon know that I've used the Amazon PA API? Is that what *"attributing a link to the Product API"* means ?

Comment: so did you find answer to this